# gfvs-mount share password-protected

Tags: linux, samba, cifs

I want to mount using gfvs-mount samba remote server with password-protected, so I do:

```
gfvs-mount smb://ip/share
```

but I need to insert everytime username, I'd like avoid username but have only prompted password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
gvfs-mount smb://IP\;username@IP/share
```

only password will be prompted

```
gvfs-mount -l
```

to show mounted share

Answer (score 1):

I am using the same solution as watchmansky but removed the IP\; part:

```
gvfs-mount smb://username@host/share
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a credentials file for the user in the home directory:

```
**Filename: ~/.gvfs_credentials**
<username>
<domain name>
<password>
```

And then add a '*gvfs-mount*' command to my *.profile* script for each share for gvfs to mount, giving it the credentials we saved earlier:

```
**Filename: ~/.profile**
gvfs-mount smb://<servername>/<sharename> < .gvfs_credentials
```

The benefit is you can just change the password in the .gvfs_credentials file.

The bad side is that the password is saved as unencrypted plaintext.

Hope this helps someone :)